# Add WMSLayer to Map in ArcGIS API 4.x

Tags: javascript, geoserver, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to add a WMSLayer to new Map with ArcGIS API 4.x from local Geoserver. However, I get this error: XML Parse Error.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
require([
    "esri/Map", 
    "esri/layers/WMSLayer", 
    "esri/views/MapView", 
    "esri/geometry/SpatialReference"
], function (Map, WMSLayer, MapView, SpatialReference) {
        const lyrSpe = new WMSLayer ({
        url : "http://localhost:9090/geoserver/atlas_Ext/wms?",
        customParameters : {
            "REQUEST" : "GetMap", 
            "SERVICE" : "WMS", 
            "VERSION" : "1.3.0", 
            "LAYERS" : "atlas_Ext:spe_amz", 
            "BBOX" : "-120.724769592285,13.9802989959717,-85.6313323974609,33.9545745849609", 
            "WIDTH" : 768, 
            "HEIGHT" : 756, 
            "TRANSPARENT" : true, 
            "FORMAT" : "image/png",                 
            "SRC": "EPSG:4326"
        }, 
        title: "WMS_Layer"
    }); 
    const map = new Map({basemap: "satellite", layers: [lyrSpe]});
    const view = new MapView({
        container: "viewDiv", 
        map: map, 
        center: [-99.765551, 19.290255], 
        zoom: 4
    }); 
});
```

Can you help me please.

Comment: you need to look in the network tab and add details of the actual URL being requested and what the response contains to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: It says `XML parse error`...are you sure the xml file that's being request is valid (has proper syntax, etc.)?